# Applying &:before to top level of menu only

Tags: css, sass

I have the following html structure that I cannot edit:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am using this SASS to style it so a triangle is inserted before the text inside link:

```
#menu{
  width:300px;
  .nav li{
    a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDDE;
                &:before {
                content: "";
                display: inline-block;
                width: 0; 
                height: 0; 
                border-top: 4px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
                border-left: 4px solid #333;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                position: relative;
            }
  }
  }

  .sub-menu {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Codepen with bootstrap added here: http://codepen.io/GuerrillaCoder/pen/jPBMqG?editors=110

The effect I desire is for this to only be inserted in top level of menu, and also if the class "active" is there the triangle will point down instead of right.

I am going round in circles, I cannot figure out how to either remove the inserted content, hide it or alter the selector for just the top level.  Also trying to stop my underline spilling into sub-menu.

Can someone give me any tips?

Comment: I don't know how SASS affects if but you can combine pseudo selectors. Either use selector>selector to specify only the direct descendants or you could say :first-child::before.

Comment: I think the & makes it recursive but if I remove it then it stops working all together.

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  Unless Sass is generating the incorrect CSS, only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: Oh no, the troll is here again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only apply the generic rules (the ones that can/will affect the `:after` pseudo-element all of the time) to your `.nav a` selector (which is a broad selector, covering all `a` elements in your `.nav`).

Then, be specific in targeting just the ones you want for the special behviour:

```
  .nav{
    a{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDDE;
        &:before {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        position: relative;

      }
    }
    & > li > a:before {
        content: "";
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #333;
    }
    & > li.active a:before {
        border-top: 4px solid #333;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    }
```

I've used descendant selectors to ensure only the direct children of the top level get affected.

Full example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOxXpG